# How do you convert from binary to IEEE754 when the last decimal isn't 5?

Tags: math, binary, floating-point, ieee-754

Everything I can find on this says to simply multiply by 2 until the decimal resolves to zero, but this only works if the last decimal is 5.

In my particular case the number to convert is 98765.4321, how would I convert this (or any other decimal that doesn't resolve) to IEEE754?

Comment: Quick answer: Keep on going with the conversion process until you have generated enough bits to round to the desired IEEE-754 binary target format, utilizing the rounding mode of your choice. Long answer: It is complicated, multiple papers have been written on the subject, e.g. [this one](http://www.cesura17.net/~will/professional/research/papers/howtoread.pdf)

Comment: @njuffa That does seem to be an answer, not just a comment.

Comment: @PatriciaShanahan Thanks for the endorsement, but as-is, this would make for a lousy answer, IMHO. I should have some time later tonight to provide something better,

Answer (score 2):

I will assume the question is as follows: We are given a number specified as a sequence of decimal digits that possibly includes a decimal fraction, and possibly makes use of scientific notation. How do we correctly convert this number into one of the binary floating-point formats specified by the [IEEE 754](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_floating_point#IEEE_754-2008) floating-point standard, i.e. `binary16` (half precision), `binary32` (single precision), `binary64` (double precision), or `binary128` (quadruple precision)?

As you noted, most decimal numbers cannot be represented exactly in a binary floating-point format. That means we need to chose one of the IEEE-754 rounding mode that should be used to determine the final result: Round towards positive infinity ("up"), round towards negative infinity ("down"), round towards zero (truncate), or round towards-nearest-or-even ("nearest"). Decimal-to-binary conversion typically uses the last mode listed, round towards-nearest-or-even, as this minimizes overall error in the conversion.

Conceptually, our task is simple. Carry out the conversion process until we have generated enough bits to make a correct rounding decision. Clearly, we will often need more bits than provided by the target format. However, we cannot tell a-priory exactly how many bits we will need, as some hard to round cases will generate results very close to a tie-case. The take-home message is that some parts of our algorithm will require the use of some sort of extended precision (or multi-precision) arithmetic, and we need to develop a criterion for determining when we have generated enough bits for correct rounding.

The fundamental algorithms for correct conversions were developed over a couple of decades in the past century, and are described in the following publications:

David W. Matula, "In-and-out conversions". *Communications of the ACM*, Vol. 11, No. 1 (Jan. 1968), pp. 47-50

David W. Matula,  "A Formalization of Floating-Point Numeric Base Conversion". *IEEE Transactions on Computers*, Vol 10, No. 8 (Aug. 1970), pp. 681-692 ([online](http://www.acsel-lab.com/arithmetic/arith1/papers/ARITH1_Matula.pdf))

William D. Clinger, "How to Read Floating Point Numbers Accurately". *SIGPLAN Notices*, Vol. 25, No. 6 (June 1990), pp. 92-101 ([online](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.45.4152&rep=rep1&type=pdf))

David M. Gay, "Correctly rounded binary-decimal and decimal-binary conversions". Technical Report 90--10, AT&T Bell Laboraties, November 1990. ([online](http://ampl.com/REFS/rounding.pdf))

A fresh look at this research area is provided by the following publications:

Michel Hack, "On Intermediate Precision Required for Correctly-Rounding Decimal-to-Binary Floating-Point Conversion." In *Proceedings of Real Numbers and Computers (RNC'6)*, Nov. 2004, pp. 113-133 ([online](https://www.researchgate.net/profile/Jean-Michel_Muller/publication/253481041_A_proven_correctly_rounded_logarithm_in_double-precision/links/54db2cc50cf2ba88a68f5354.pdf#page=114))

Aubrey Jaffer, "Easy Accurate Reading and Writing of Floating-Point Numbers". arXiv:1310.8121, draft v6 (Jan. 2015), ([online](https://arxiv.org/abs/1310.8121))

Although the fundamental algorithms have been around for twenty-five years, they are of considerable complexity, and the "devil is in the details". *Correct* implementations of decimal-to-brinary conversions continue to prove elusive. Over the past 5 years, Rick Regan's blog ["Exploring Binary"](http://www.exploringbinary.com/) has chronicled a number of defects in the decimal-to-binary conversion functionality of widely used software, such as 
[Microsoft Visual C/C++](http://www.exploringbinary.com/visual-c-plus-plus-strtod-still-broken/), 
[glibc](http://www.exploringbinary.com/glibc-strtod-incorrectly-converts-2-to-the-negative-1075/), 
and [PHP](http://www.exploringbinary.com/a-better-fix-for-the-php-2-2250738585072011e-308-bug/), 
where the last item would cause an infinite loop that might be exploited for denial-of-service attacks.

A paper by Vern Paxson and William Kahan addresses the issue of hard-to-round cases in decimal-to-binary conversion, and gives some examples that demonstrate how many additional bits beyond target precision may be required for correct rounding:

V. Paxson and W. Kahan, "A Program for Testing IEEE Decimal–Binary Conversion". Manuscript, May 1991 ([online](http://www.icir.org/vern/papers/testbase-report.pdf))

Additional hard-to-round cases for IEEE-754 `binary64` were listed in a 1996 [posting](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!original/comp.arch.arithmetic/uDGiskofu4I/stg9JR8vXE0J) to the newsgroup `comp.arch.arithmetic` by Fred Tydeman.

The following paper describes a test framework for testing conversions, however the files containing the test vectors were no longer accessible online the last time I checked:

Brigitte Verdonk, Annie Cuyt, and Dennis Verschaeren. "A precision-and range-independent tool for testing floating-point arithmetic II: conversions." *ACM Transactions on Mathematical Software*, Vol. 27, No. 1 (Mar. 2001), pp. 119-140. ([draft online](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.35.7408&rep=rep1&type=pdf))